# Connecting C# application to iOS device via lightning cable

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin

I haven't been able to find any resources regarding this, so I thought I'd ask here.

I have an iOS app that I am developing, as well as a C# desktop app. I'm currently able to connect the two by creating a Socket Server on the desktop app, and connecting from the iOS app. This works well, but I'd like to do this without requiring the devices being on the same network. Communicating via Usb (lightning port) seems like the logical choice, but I can't find any resources at all about how to do this. Are there any tools or best practices regarding this, or is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Peertalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk), an open source library allowing to pass `TCP` connections through the USB connection without being part of the `MFI` program. PeerTalk uses the iTunes `usbmux` system to relay TCP connections across the iOS USB connection.

Comment: This looks like it'll be perfect for what I need, except for the fact that I'm using Xamarin, and there doesn't seem to be a binding. I'm pretty sure I can make one though, unless you know of one that exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use Peertalk, since I'm using Xamarin for my project. However, I spent the last week researching and documenting what I learned, and I posted it as a blog post here

http://thecodewash.blogspot.com/2017/05/communicating-with-your-ios-app-over.html

Hopefully this helps others.